# Dataflow OutOfMemoryError while reading small tables from BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a [pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Jyb.png) reading data from BigQuery and processing historical data for various calendar years. It **fails with OutOfMemoryError** errors **if the input data is small** (~500MB)

On startup it reads from BigQuery about 10.000 elements/sec, after short time it slows down to hundreds elements/s then it hangs completely.

Observing 'Elements Added' on the next processing step (BQImportAndCompute), the value increases and then decreases again. That looks to me like some already loaded data is dropped and then loaded again.

Stackdriver Logging console contains errors with various stack traces that contain java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, for example:

> Error reporting workitem progress update to Dataflow service:

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.BigQueryAvroReader$BigQueryAvroFileIterator.getProgress(BigQueryAvroReader.java:145)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.setProgressFromIteratorConcurrent(ReadOperation.java:397)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.setProgressFromIterator(ReadOperation.java:389)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$1.run(ReadOperation.java:206)
```

I would suspect that there is a problem with topology of the pipe, but running the same pipeline

1. **locally** with DirectPipelineRunner **works** fine
2. **in cloud** with DataflowPipelineRunner **on large dataset** (5GB, for another year) **works** fine

I assume problem is how Dataflow parallelizes and distributes work in the pipeline. Are there any possibilities to inspect or influence it?

Comment: Any details on what `BQImportAndCompute` is doing? Also, `BQConcat` looks like a `Flatten`, is that correct? Is there a specific job ID that we should look at to see what was going on?

Comment: BQImportAndCompute is reading TableRow and converting to another POJO. Yes, BQConcat is Flatten.

For example jobID 2016-04-22_07_09_50-6916524826145032691.  In fact, all the manually cancelled jobs then did not complete. https://www.evernote.com/l/ADtUXFwm92ROr5sTXqEUVrcfhUwQfrHctFM

Comment: Also, I've found out later, that after throwing OutOfMemory, JVM did not exit. I've connected to worker and tried to kill JVM process. Then more data was procesed until next OOM. After few repeats then pipe failed because of too many retries.

Comment: and for comparison, the same pipeline (java code)

Job 2016-04-22_05_01_130-3684926617487173331
input size 4.07 GB - completed.


Jobs 2016-04-21_08_51_03-9649478815118530360, 2016-04-21_10_04_12-4127814452160753674
input size 339MB - failed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here doesn't seem to be related to the size of the BigQuery table, but likely the number of BigQuery sources being used and the rest of the pipeline.

1. Instead of reading from multiple BigQuery sources and flattening them have you tried reading from a query that pulls in all the information? Doing that in a single step should simplify the pipeline and also allow BigQuery to execute better (one query against multiple tables vs. multiple queries against individual tables).
2. Another possible problem is if there is a high degree of fan-out within or after the `BQImportAndCompute` operation. Depending on the computation being done there, you may be able to reduce the fan-out using clever `CombineFn`s or `WindowFn`s. If you want help figuring out how to improve that path, please share more details about what is happening after the `BQImportAndCompute`.

Comment: I put the source code of pipeline on github [dash-pipeline](https://github.com/ceresnam/dash-pipeline) I'm going to try reducing fan-out degree.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging with Stackdriver?

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/debugging-data-transformations-using-cloud-dataflow-and-stackdriver-debugger